# vboxmanage.exe error could not find a registered machine named

Tags: cmd, virtualbox

Хочу поставить OS X на виртуальную машину. Следую [одному из самых популярных туториалов на ютубе](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wI3ng69kTD0), хотя в принципе в каждом туториале сразу после создания машины предлагается ввести в командную строку следующее: `VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "NAME HERE" --cpuidset 00000001 000106e5 00100800 0098e3fd bfebfbff`. Ну и тут я получаю такой ответ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
  У кого-то в комментах под видео возникла такая же проблема, но автор туториала не смог сказать в ответ ничего лучше, кроме как "проверьте правильность написания имени". Я прошерстил весь интернет, но ничего конкретного не нашёл. Как такое вообще может быть? Ведь машина на самом деле существует, такими заявлениями компьютер выставляет меня сумасшедшим :|

Comment: Попробуйте запустить командную строку без прав администратора.

Comment: @kff и правда, спасибо! Хотя в туториале говорится запускать от имени админа. Можете записать в ответ, помечу правильным.